# C# Access Db update query not working

Tags: c#, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to update an access table with the code noted below. however, the update does not execute. It doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't update the database. Any suggestions?

```
string Const = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\\Db\\test.accdb";      

OleDbCommand Cmd;
OleDbConnection con22 = new OleDbConnection(Const );
con22.Open();

string sql = "UPDATE CostT SET tFormSent='" + Selection1.Text + "',TName='" + UserName.Text + "',FormDate='" + FormDate.Text + "',where ReqNum=" + ReqNum.Text;

cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con22);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con22.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Form has been Updated");
```

Comment: It *should* be throwing an error, since there's at least one syntax error.  Though given all these SQL injection vulnerabilities, there's no telling what random code you might be executing on your database.  What's the actual runtime value of the query you're executing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the query
to

```
string sql = "UPDATE CostT SET tFormSent = @selection1,TName = @UserName,FormDate = @FormDate where ReqNum = @ReqNum";
cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con22);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@selection1", Selection1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", UserName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", FromDate.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReqNum", ReqNum.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con22.Close();
```

Comment: This is perfect!! I think the SQL injections i had messed everything up. But the parameters version worked perfectly. Now i just have to learn Unions and Delete. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

Your query has a syntax error: you have a comma before your `WHERE` clause that does not belong there.

But more important: Your code is open to [SQL injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com)! Please don't insert user input directly into your query, but use parameterized queries instead!